# Sell Put Strike Price and Share Price

Tags: put-options

I have a sell put Strike @ $100. At expiry yesterday, share price is @ $100.32. Will I be exercise?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of you being assigned is very low. The strike *K<sub>p</sub>* doesn't exceed the MVPS, so automatic exercise isn't happening.

However, if the option was ITM by a certain threshold (normally $0.01), the OCC will by default offer the buyer the ability to ask for sellers of the contract series to be assigned. This is known as "exercise by exception"; in the absence of contrary instruction from a clearing member, the OCC will assign a seller, and the transaction will proceed.

On the other hand, it's still possible (theoretically) for a market participant holding / long on that same option series that you sold to exercise before 4:30pm CT the Friday that it expires even if the option is OTM. They have the *right* but **not** the *obligation* to exercise the option, regardless of the market price of the underlying relative to the strike.

***So there's no guarantee that you won't be assigned, but the practice of exercising an OTM option is rare.***

Comment: Hypothetical question.  It's expiration and (A) is long the entire call open interest in stock ABC at strike $100 and (B) is short that entire position.  No other players exist at that strike.  This $100 call ends slightly ITM.  (A) informs the OCC via his broker not to auto exercise.  Does that mean that (B) gets a free pass even though his short calls expired ITM? I'd assume so ... but?